# Interactive drawing in c++

Tags: c++, opencv, graphics, mouseevent

[image]I try to create an interactive window. I read an image from my pc and show it using opencv.I use `cvSetMouseCallback` function to get mouse position and events. I write a code that creates a rectangle on the image when a user selects points of edges of rectangle.I want to redraw it, the user click+move. But I can't find how I handle mouse release. Is there an event for this such as `EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN`?

I try to do this :

Comment: There's a similar solution in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22140880/drawing-rectangle-or-line-using-mouse-events-in-open-cv-using-python

Comment: from quick look at Kornels link the answer there is `CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP` if you need also help with the edit code  then look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20924609/2521214 for ideas