# How to continue drawing a rectangle while dragging the mouse once the left button has been clicked?

Tags: image, opencv, events

I have understood how to capture the mouse movements to draw a rectangle by first clicking the left button, then dragging the mouse and then releasing the left button. My code is as follows. However, I want continue drawing a rectangle even when I am moving the mouse over the image after I have clicked the left button.

Unfortunately, Now, the rectangle is being displayed only after I release the left button at the end.

```
# import the necessary packages
import argparse
import cv2

# initialize the list of reference points and boolean indicating
# whether cropping is being performed or not
refPt = []
cropping = False

def click_and_crop(event, x, y, flags, param):
    # grab references to the global variables
global refPt, cropping, image
drag = 0
# if the left mouse button was clicked, record the starting
# (x, y) coordinates and indicate that cropping is being
# performed
if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
    refPt = [(x, y)]
        drag = 1
    cropping = True

# check to see if the left mouse button was released
elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
    # record the ending (x, y) coordinates and indicate that
    # the cropping operation is finished
    refPt.append((x, y))
    cropping = False

    # draw a rectangle around the region of interest
    cv2.rectangle(image, refPt[0], refPt[1], (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.imshow("image", image)

elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE and drag == 1:
    #image = clone.copy()
    cv2.rectangle(image, refPt[0], (x, y), (0, 255, 0), 2)

# load the image, clone it, and setup the mouse callback function
image = cv2.imread("image_00001.jpg")
clone = image.copy()
cv2.namedWindow("image")
cv2.setMouseCallback("image", click_and_crop)

# keep looping until the 'q' key is pressed
while True:
# display the image and wait for a keypress
    cv2.imshow("image", image)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

# if the 'r' key is pressed, reset the cropping region
if key == ord("r"):
    image = clone.copy()

# if the 'c' key is pressed, break from the loop
elif key == ord("c"):
    break

# if there are two reference points, then crop the region of interest
# from teh image and display it
if len(refPt) == 2:
    roi = clone[refPt[0][1]:refPt[1][1], refPt[0][0]:refPt[1][0]]
    cv2.imshow("ROI", roi)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

# close all open windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You can start from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31376558/5008845) it's C++ code, but should get you going

Comment: Thanks @Miki I looked at it but unable to make the relevant changes to the Python code here. Can you suggest me the relevant changes?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't (Python it's not my thing ;D). I'd suggest to follow my code structure and translate line by line to Python. After all, the code is calling just OpenCV function, shouldn't be that hard to translate the calls to Python

Comment: Or you can have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28649758/5008845), but I don't guarantee ;D

Comment: just add cv2.imshow("image", image) and maybe a cv2.waitKey(1) in the MOUSEMOVE case. and clone the original image before drawing (or undo the previous drawing)

Answer (score 2):

Try below code:

```
import cv2

refPt = []

final_boundaries = []
image = None


def click_and_crop(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global refPt, image
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        refPt = [(x, y)]
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        refPt.append((x, y))
        final_boundaries.append((refPt[0],refPt[1]))
        cv2.rectangle(image, refPt[0], refPt[1], (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.imshow("image", image)
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE and flags == cv2.EVENT_FLAG_LBUTTON:
        clone = image.copy()
        cv2.rectangle(clone, refPt[0], (x, y), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.imshow("image", clone)


def main(image_name):
    global image
    image = cv2.imread("image.png") #convert to image boundary
    cv2.namedWindow("image")
    cv2.setMouseCallback("image", click_and_crop)
    cv2.imshow("image", image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    return (final_boundaries)
```